# Rewrite ans shorten switch case expression

Tags: go, switch-statement, code-readability

I have such code block where I just increment counters:

```
switch fileInfo.RequestType {
case lib.WRITE:
    WriteCounter += 1
case lib.READ:
    ReadCounter += 1
}
```

It seems to me that this snippet doesn't look like a idiomatic golang code. Can it be done more short and "elegant"?

Comment: Shorter isn't more elegant. Maybe use the increment operator if you're trying to save a few characters, but otherwise I'm not sure what you expect to accomplish.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that statement.  "Tricks" so save space, may be ok for showing off, but they usually result in harder to read code and in some cases, considerably slower code.  Remember, even c, less bytes in your code does not necessarily compile to less assembler instructions.  That being said, I would use the increment operators.

Answer (score 1):

More idiomatic:

```
switch fileInfo.RequestType {
case lib.Write:
    writeCounter++
case lib.Read:
    readCounter++
}
```

Comment: take it into account

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what elegant here mean. Maybe putting the `case` statement to be inline?

```
switch fileInfo.RequestType {
    case lib.WRITE: WriteCounter += 1
    case lib.READ: ReadCounter += 1
}
```

Writing style like above are valid, but it doesn't follow the `gofmt` standard.